# Group all subsections together in TOC

Tags: tocloft

Is there a way to group all e.g. subsections together in the TOC (at the beginning of the document) under a part heading? I'm currently using `tocloft`. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\newpage

\cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{All the Sections}{}

\section{blah}

\subsection{blah1.1}

\subsection{blah1.2}

\section{blah2}

\subsection{blah2.1}

\subsection{blah2.2}

\section{blah3}


\cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{All the Subsections}{}


\end{document}
```

This obviously compiles as:

[image: Contents with subsections under sections]

I want something like this (obviously with the correct section numbering):

[image: contents with subsections together but with incorrect numbering]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure what you want can be accomplished by [`etoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc). I don't have time to put in a full MWE right now, but here's how I would do it:

- I will print your ToC in two passes.
- The first pass I will print to depth level 2 so that the sections are printed.
- The second past I will print to depth level 3 AFTER using `\etocsetlevel{section}{6}` to make sections "invisible".

In the current manual, the commands you needs are in sections

- 11. A powerful functionality of etoc: the re-assignment of
      levels with `\etocsetlevel`
- 12. The `\etocsettocdepth` and `\etocsetnexttocdepth`
      commands

Pay attention to also the boxed text on pages 18-19 which describes something similar to what you want.